# From 2 table to 2 arraylist

Tags: java, android, jdbc, arraylist

I have 2 `arraylist`

```
public ArrayList<Double> latitude = new ArrayList<Double>();
public ArrayList<Double> longitude = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and 2 table in database: `latitude` and `longitude`

I can send from lists to tables, but have problem with sending from table to list.
I think i working with this application too long and do some stupid mistake.

```
String sql = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM table";


            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next()){

                latitude  = rs.getDouble("latitude");
                longitude = rs.getDouble("longitude");

            }
            rs.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are in fact querying the table and fetching the values in it but you are not actually adding them to the arrayList ,the problem is in the 2 lines:

```
            latitude  = rs.getDouble("latitude");
            longitude = rs.getDouble("longitude");
```

to add a value to your arrayList you use:

```
            latitude.add(rs.getDouble("latitude"));
            longitude.add(rs.getDouble("longitude"));
```

hope that helps.